# FFI from 64-bit haskell to 64-bit windows dll causes access violation

Tags: windows, haskell, dll, 32bit-64bit, ffi

I am running Windows 7 (64 bit).
Using version 2014.2.0.0 of Haskell (64 and 32 bit).

With a 32-bit dll and a 32-bit Haskell program this works just fine.
With a 64-bit dll and a 64-bit Haskell program this does not work. Instead I get an access violation.

```
First-chance exception at 0x0000000000000000 in TestInterop.exe:
0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.
```

**c++ code** (built as 64-bit dll):

```
BOOL __stdcall DllMain(HINSTANCE, DWORD, void*)
{
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)  uint64_t ReverseDigits(uint64_t number)
{
    uint64_t result = 0;
    while (number)
    {
        result *= 10;
        result += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The **Haksell** code

```
module Main where
import Foreign.C
foreign import ccall unsafe "ReverseDigits" interopReverseDigits :: CULLong -> IO CULLong

main = do
    x <- interopReverseDigits(1234)
    if x == 4321
        then putStrLn "Successfully Called Test"
        else putStrLn "Call to test failed"</code></pre>
```

Is there some sort of special thunk I need to perform in Haskell for this to work?

Comment: Hopefully a Haskell expert can provide a specific answer, but note that the 64-bit calling conventions are often less lenient than the 32-bit ones, i.e., a mistake that might be harmless in 32-bit can cause crashes in 64-bit.

Comment: Works for me, on 64-bit Windows 7, Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0 (which is ghc 7.8.3).  I don't have 32-bit ghc installed.

Comment: Thanks @ja. I'll look at the compiler options for my DLL and settings for ghc (as it is the same version you have).

Comment: @ja., what compiler are you using for the DLL?

Comment: I couldn't get it to compile in VS (haven't set up a DLL project from scratch in years), so I used the gcc that comes with Git Bash.